# Emacs - CEDET startup problems

Tags: emacs, cedet

i have installed the cedet-extension for my emacs-editor. I have downoaded it from the specific sourceforge-page and have used the make-command. Then i have added this line in the .emacs config-file:

```
(load-file "~/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")
```

Then i get the following error message:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
`/home/myName/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, /home/myName/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el
```

When starting emacs with the --debug-init option it says:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load
file""/home/myName/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")
load("/home/myName/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el" nil nil t)
load-file("~/cedet-1.1/common/cedet.el")
eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/myName/.emacs" nil t)
Reading at buffer position 42
load-with-code-conversion("/home/myName/.emacs" "/home/myName/.emacs t
t)
load("~/.emacs" t t)
```

I dont understand this because the cedet.el - file is on the right place... can someone tell where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the devel file.

`(load-file "~/cedet-1.1/common/cedet-devel-load.el")`

Be sure you initialize your cedet before the emacs one (load it in the beginning of your init file)

If you have a recent emacs (>=24.1) try with this version of CEDET: http://sourceforge.net/p/cedet/git/ci/master/tree/